# Window function in pyspark - strange behavior

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Pyspark window functions extensively in my code. But it seems to be not working properly.

But `i'm getting the correct results only for the last record by order by column` for the partition.

Documentation says , it is experimental, can we use it in production systems
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window

**Sample code:**

```
invWindow = Window.partitionBy(masterDrDF["ResId"], masterDrDF["vrsn_strt_dts"]).orderBy(masterDrDF["vrsn_strt_dts"]).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

max(when(invDetDF["InvoiceItemType"].like('ABD%'), 1).otherwise(0)).over(invWindow).alias("ABD_PKG_IN")
```

Comment: Could you please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That makes it easier to help.

Comment: Interesting bit. You're creating window function based on `masterDrDF` dataframe, but later use it with other - `invDetDF`... I've never tried  such think..

Comment: On another note, we're using window functions and all issues were related to our code, rather than framework. I wouldn't worry about "experiment".